# Dash - Uploading extremely large .txt (3 million rows) using Upload component

Tags: python, database, csv, plotly, plotly-dash

New to dash, having trouble uploading my .csv files with the standard example code used [here](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/upload). I tried uploading normal or small size .txt files and the code works just fine. However, when I try to load very large .csv files (2 GB,  close to 3 million rows and 11 columns), the page immediately breaks and shows the Google Chrome error ["Aw, Snap!"](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95669?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid).

I then tried to upload the .txt in compressed .zip format (code below).

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Upload(
        id='upload-data',
        children=html.Div([
            'Drag and Drop or ',
            html.A('Select Files')
        ]),
        style={
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '60px',
            'lineHeight': '60px',
            'borderWidth': '1px',
            'borderStyle': 'dashed',
            'borderRadius': '5px',
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'margin': '10px'
        },
        # Allow multiple files to be uploaded
        multiple=True

    ),
    html.Div(id='output-data-upload')
])

@app.callback(Output('output-data-upload', 'children'),
              Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
              State('upload-data', 'filename'),
              State('upload-data', 'last_modified'))
def update_output(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates):
    for content, name, date in zip(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates):
        content_type, content_string = content.split(',')
        content_decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
        zip_str = io.BytesIO(content_decoded)
        zip_obj = ZipFile(zip_str, 'r')

        with zip_obj.open("my_original_filename.txt") as z:
            df = pd.read_csv(z)
            print(df.head())
```

The code works well in normal size compressed .csv files. However, when I pass the compressed version of my very large .csv file (which, in .zip format, now makes up 500 Mb), the `list_of_contents` parameter is empty. So the file is being ignored outright.

Working with very large .txt files is necessary for me, since I am working at a neuroscience lab where very long EEG readings (8 to 10 hours) are our bread and butter. How can I get this data into a Dash application?

Comment: It seems your application is embedded in a server. Do you store (even temporarily) those file on disk? Can you tell us what is the file system of the server ? At the server side, when using debug mode, what is the error in the logs? Out of memory? It seems the file is too big to be processed or passed by the server web framework. So if you find out why, you may pin down what to do to solve your issue.

Comment: The application is not embedded in a server. I wrote a scientific R library dedicated to some specific EEG topics, and I am working on launching a Python application that uses that library. The backend is done, the Python code works. I have the files on disk, and all future users will have other files on disk that they'll need to upload

Comment: The idea is that every scientist in the lab should be able to upload an EEG reading in .csv format and use this Python/R integrated software I wrote to analyze their EEGs. That's why making the app capable of uploading large files is key.

Comment: Well then I don't understand the need of Chrome and HTML

Comment: Just trying to help here and getting enough information to understand where your problem is. Do you have any logs in your process that we can compare when it works and when it does not? That where I'll start. Additionally 2Go is a limit for some file system, just want to be sure it is not your case. Not sure it is clear what your architecture is (web or not) but if the error is there that would be helpful to anyone to better describe the full process. Why do you think the error arise a the python side? Anyway see [mcve] and [ask] ans update your question accordingly.

Comment: Also it can simply be your browser that is limited. https://www.smartfile.com/blog/file-size-limits-for-uploads-through-web-browsers/